# ELEMENTOR BACKGROUND URL VIDEO AND SLIDER IMAGE NOT LOADING

Tags: wordpress, elementor

I've inserted an URL for the video bg, but couldn't find the video loaded in the live site after the update. Can we view the video rendered in the elementor preview.
Grey colour area replacing the video bg
[image]

Elementor bg
[image]

Comment: Hi @vishal, Can you be more specific about what you have,want and getting in error , Is it possible to provide Screenshot of each by edit this question. that will help us to answer your question. thanks

Comment: I've added the screenshots. thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you put the URL in local, after deploying you need to replace the url of the whole site with the new URL.
for example: **localhost/demo -> www.demo.com** , replace like this.
download the search and replace file from github and follow the direction.